# Propagating selection from within UITableViewCell to UITableView delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am subclassing UITableViewCell and adding gesture recognizers to it. One of the gesture recognizers is attached to a subview of the cell's content view, and only when the user taps this subview should the cell be "selected". I want the cell to propagate this selection up to its containing table view so that the `–[id<UITableViewDelegate> tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` method is called.

Several problems:

- From inside the UITableViewCell subclass, I don't know what index path I'm at (and I don't want to store it as a property unless absolutely necessary).
- From inside the UITableViewCell subclass, I don't have a reference to the UITableView nor the UITableViewDelegate. (Again, I would want to avoid having to explicitly declare these.)
- I don't want to create my own delegate to detect selection events, I want to use the built in mechanism (i.e. didSelectRowAtIndexPath: if possible).
- If I try the naive approach and just call `self.selected = YES` on my subclass, the cell appears highlighted, but the delegate's didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called.

In other words, is there a way to leverage Apple's didSelectRowAtIndexPath: from my own custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is to create your own table cell delegate protocol (despite you saying you don't want that).

Then your table view controller can be the delegate. Then the table view controller can lookup the cell's indexPath and call the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

This has the advantage that your custom cell doesn't care how the event is processed. It simply tells its delegate that something happened. The cell doesn't need any knowledge of its table or indexPath.

Your view controller has the job of linking up your desired functionality. This is how it should be done. Clean separation of duties.

Another thing to consider is that the implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and the implementation of your custom cell's delegate method should each call a shared method that handles the same logic. This makes more sense than having one delegate method call another delegate method directly.